# Electric field - when the charge oscillates

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If we have an electron moving up and down(oscilating), it produces EM wave.

Let's put charge at (0,0) and it starts oscillating - goes up to 0, 3 and then comes down to 0, -3 and repeating. When it moves from 0,0 to 0,1, after some time, at 10,0 point - electric field would change.

I'm interested what exactly would change at 10,0 point after charge moved to 0,1 ? Is it electric field strength - would it decrease ? If so, why ? is it because distance increased - i.e distance between 0,1 - 10,0 is bigger than between 0,0 and 10,0 ?

**note that I'm interested in this specific point. It's kind of hard to grasp the whole explanation of EM waves, so for now, I'd love to get an answer only to this and bit by bit, I will approach the better understanding of the whole flow - I have read lots of things before asking this, but still hard - so trying to understand it in an more intuitive way.**

Comment: *distance between 0,1 - 10,0 is bigger than between 0,0 and 10,0* Are you claiming that 9.9 is bigger than 10.0?

Comment: sorry, should have written lower, but the point is since distance changes, is it electric field strength that changes because the distance changed between 0,0 - 10,0 and 0,1 - 10,0 ?

Comment: What I'm focusing is if the charge oscilates from 0,0 to 3,0 (not going down though) - which means it just goes up to 3,0 and stops, even this should produce some kind of wave right ? as Electric field strength decrease would propagate through space while charge moves to 1,0 - then to 2,0, e.t.c. Can't we call this a wave though ? just electric field wave ?

Comment: A moving charge produces a magnetic field in addition to an electric field. Both the electric field and the magnetic field will oscillate as the charge moves back and forth, so the resulting wave is called an *electromagnetic* wave. The changing distance is the primary cause of the change in the electric field strength, I think; the math is a bit complicated.

Comment: I get that both changing E and B produce EM wave, but trying to understand how the wave propagates, so for this, I need to understand easier things first. If we forget about Magnetic field(imagine it doesn't exist), can't we say oscilating charge produces changing E field hence Electric field wave ?

Comment: For purposes of intuition, I’ll say yes. However, it is an oversimplification and therefore not the whole story.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146170/discussion-between-matt-and-ghoster).